# Не работает выдача ролей в discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Я хочу, чтобы бот выдавал роль, id которой получит из БД. Но у меня не работает.

Вот ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/runner/manul/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "main.py", line 86, in test
await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
File "/home/runner/manul/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 777, in add_roles
await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/runner/manul/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/runner/manul/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/home/runner/manul/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Код команды:
https://pastebin.com/zvmp1RXS

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT verify_role FROM role WHERE id = {ctx.author.guild.id}")
    verify_role = cursor.fetchone()
    if verify_role != None:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=verify_role[0])
        await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Полный код ошибки: https://pastebin.com/udiFRHaq